# Why #define values inside an enum?

Tags: c, enums, macros

I ran across something that's odd to me while reading one of the Linux headers, `<linux/rtnetlink.h>`:

```
/* RTnetlink multicast groups */
enum rtnetlink_groups {
        RTNLGRP_NONE,
#define RTNLGRP_NONE            RTNLGRP_NONE
        RTNLGRP_LINK,
#define RTNLGRP_LINK            RTNLGRP_LINK
        RTNLGRP_NOTIFY,
#define RTNLGRP_NOTIFY          RTNLGRP_NOTIFY
        RTNLGRP_NEIGH,
#define RTNLGRP_NEIGH           RTNLGRP_NEIGH
        RTNLGRP_TC,
#define RTNLGRP_TC              RTNLGRP_TC
        RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR,
#define RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR     RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR
/* ... etc, pattern continues ... */
};
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the reason for the macros here or what difference they would make. What purpose does this serve?

Comment: Is it inside a class?

Comment: It looks like someone wanted to convert `enum` into defines or vice-versa and forgot to remove the unused lines. but no, I wouldn't expect it to be in linux kernel...

Comment: @JohnKugelman: That's the only reason I can think of. You should post it as an answer. (Before I do.)

Comment: Obviously, there is no reason to define any macro that does not revolve around the preprocessor.  My first guess as to the particular reason here is the same as JohnKugelman's -- there seems otherwise little advantage to defining a macro whose replacement text is the same as its name.

Comment: Yes, I think you guys are right :-). Since netlink changes across releases it would make it easier to write code that can be compatible across them.

Comment: @Barmar Nice duplicate. Especially the [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/cpp/Self_002dReferential-Macros.html#Self_002dReferential-Macros) in the comments to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes the constants visible to the preprocessor. You could use `#ifdef` to check if a particular constant is available.

Comment: There seem to be no occurrences of `#if RTNLGRP...` or `#ifdef RTNLGRP...` in the current Linux sources, but that's almost certainly what the `#define` directives are intended for.

Comment: Also, it would fail if it were already defined to something else.